# Defining multiple controllers in the same module

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried the code below with adding one ButtonCtrl and one FooterCtrl but that didn't work.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ngRoute'])

.controller('ButtonCtrl', [function() {

    this.nextButtonTitle = "Next";
    this.backButtonTitle = "Back";

    this.adminButtonTitle = "Admin Login";
    this.loginButtonTitle = "Log in";

    this.submitButtonTitle = "Submit";

}, 'FooterCtrl', function(){

    this.showTime = false;
}]);
```

How do you add (if you can) multiple controllers to the same angular.module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('ButtonCtrl', [function() {
        // ...
    }])
    .controller('FooterCtrl', [function() {
        // ...
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple controller in module like this

```
angular
    .module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('ButtonCtrl', function (){
        //controller 1 stuff
    })
    .controller('FooterCtrl', function (){
        //controller 2 stuff
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
var app=angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl1',function(){
  ...
});
app.controller('ctrl2',function(){
  ...
});
...
```